# IPFS Angular11 ipfs-http-client new IpfsHttpClient = Error: export 'AbortController', Multiaddr

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ipfs

Hello I have issue with `ipsf-http-client` using angular. On return `new IpfsHttpClient()` I have missing `Multiaddr`, `anySignal`, `AbortController` and other exports. Also I have  error: This expression is not constructable, (.../ipfs-http-client/types/src/index")' has `no construct signatures`. Please for hints how to solve it or how to correctly implement ipsf-http-client in angular application

```
Angular CLI: 12.1.4
Node: 14.17.3
Package Manager: npm 6.14.13
OS: win32 x64
Python: 3.10
```

inside tsconfig:

```
"skipLibCheck": true,
"target": "es2017",
"module": "es2020",
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "dom",
  "DOM.Iterable",
  "es2015", 
  "es2015.iterable",
],
"paths" : {
  "crypto": ["./node_modules/crypto-browserify"],
  "stream": ["./node_modules/stream-browserify"],
  "assert": ["./node_modules/assert-plus"],
  "http": ["./node_modules/stream-http"],
  "https": ["./node_modules/https-browserify"],
  "os": ["./node_modules/os-browserify"],
},
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

Below is main ipfs init token.

```
import { Injectable, InjectionToken, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import IpfsHttpClient from 'ipfs-http-client';

export const ipfsToken = new InjectionToken('The IPFS Token', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => {
    try {
      return new IpfsHttpClient('ipfs.infura.io', '5001', {
        protocol: 'https'
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error', err);
      throw new Error('Unable to access IPFS node daemon on Infura network');
    }
  }
});
```

I can prevent constructable error with solution below, but still I have Missing Multiaddr, anySignal, AbortController and other exports.

```
import { Injectable, InjectionToken, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import IpfsHttpClient from 'ipfs-http-client';

export const ipfsToken = new InjectionToken('The IPFS Token', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => {
    let contextClass : any = IpfsHttpClient;
    let context: IpfsHttpClient.IPFSHTTPClient = new contextClass('ipfs.infura.io', '5001', {
        protocol: 'https'
      });

    try {
        console.log("IPFS");
        
      return context;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error', err);
      throw new Error('Unable to access IPFS node daemon on Infura network');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After 2 days of getting the annoying `Multiaddr`, `anySignal` and `AbortController` not found error in my ionic project, I notice that I were using the incorrect **ipfs** package version. To elaborate:

I installed **ipfs** with: `npm install --save ipfs-http-client` . The [official package documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-http-client/v/52.0.4-rc.4#install) describes this command in the Installation section. The command installed **ipfs** version 54.0.2 (I checked out in the `package.json` file in the project working directory).

The official npm command in the [official package documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-http-client/v/52.0.4-rc.4#install) (check out top right corner) is `npm i ipfs-http-client@52.0.4-rc.4`.

After deleting the `package.json` **ipfs** section and the `node_module` folder, I ran the `npm i ipfs-http-client@52.0.4-rc.4` and reinstalled all packages using `npm install`. This time it worked out without any errors.

PS: I believe that the release version in the npm manager is mistaken with a development version.